# Filter entity collection for form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm looking for best practices to fill a dropdown with certain entities. There is a rolesystem in which a table holds the permission for the entities. So imagine objects *projects*, *users* and *userProjects*. Last one contains userId, projectId and a few permission. In a form the user can choose those projects for which the user is granted.

Sure there are many ways to achieve this. For example a certain central service could return a prepared querybuilder that can be passed to entity form type. But in my opinion the more atractive solution would be a service that returns an ArrayCollection of granted entities. But how to bind them on a choice control? I guess that would be a good job for a modeltransformer but .. what would you recommend?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want it - create [EntityChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/EntityChoiceList.php) and pass it to form as [choice_list](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list) to [choice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) field.

Comment: Sounds great! Would you recommend doing it this way?

Comment: Why not? :) Typical I am using simple choice list or object list, but entity field internally use EntityChoiceList.